# question about passing const inside a function in c

Tags: c, function, constants

I have two questions with usage of const as an argument in C:-

1. Can a pointer be modified when we pass "const *p" as an input argument to a static BOOL and void functions. In which case it is possible? If not possible how can we do it with the following example?**

for example:-

```
main()
{
  int const *p = 1;
  BOOL(*p);
}
static BOOL(const *p)
{
  *p = 10;
  printf("*p = %d\n", x);
  void(*p);
}
------------------------------------
void(*p)
{
  A(*p);
}
A(*p)
{
  *p = 0;
}
```

**2. Do we have any difference between "CONST int *p" and "int const *p" ?**

Comment: do you know the diff between: **int* const ptr** and **const int* ptr** or even better **const int* const ptr**

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 different cases in related to pointer and const:

1)pointer to const value:
This is a pointer to point to a const value and should put const keyword before type.
For example:

```
  const int var = 7;
  const int *ptr = &var;
```

2)const pointer:
This type of pointer just initialize in declaration and can  not modify.
To declare should put const keyword between * and name of pointer.
for example:

```
  int var = 7;
  int *const ptr = &var;
```

3)const pointer to const value:
This type of pointer is const pointer to point to const value. To declare should put const keyword before type and after *. For example:

```
  int var = 5;
  const int *const ptr = &var;
```

Answer (score 2):

CV qualifier is left-associative, `const T` is the same as `T const`.

For example

1. `const T *p` = `T const *p`, so `p` is *mutable*, but `*p` is *immutable*
2. `T * const p`, `p` is *immutable*, while `*p` is *mutable*
3. `T const * const p`, both `p` and `*p` are *immutable*

Comment: in the 3rd case you mean: 
const T * const p, both p and *p are immutable (OR)
T const * const p, both p and *p are immutable ?

Comment: @SasankSaiSujanAdapa both are the same, as mentioned in ```1```

Answer (score 0):

this here: `const int *ptr` is a `pointer to const value` meaning you can not change the value of the variable the pointer is pointing to...

```
const int value = 5;
const int* ptr = &value;
*ptr = 0; //<-- this is invalid
```

now, this here: `int *const ptr` is a `const pointer` meaning the address value hold by the pointer can not be changed

```
int value1 = 0;
int value2 = 1;
 
int* const ptr = &value1;
ptr = &value2; // <-- this is invalid
```